# convert heif/heic to jpg using gpac

Tags: jpeg, hevc, mp4box, heif

I'm trying to convert HEIC to JPG using GPAC/MP4Box.  I have been able to get small JPG "tiles" for a single HEIC file but I can't figure out how to get one large JPG.

Commands are like:

```
% MP4Box -dump-item 1:path=tile1.hevc iphonesample.heic
% ffmpeg -i tile1.hevc -frames:v 1 -q:v 1 -an tile1.jpg
```

Comment: you would have to stitch all tiles together. maybe check out https://github.com/monostream/tifig its a util doing exactly that

Answer (score 1):

Once you have all HEVC files extracted, create a text file

> file file1.hevc
>
> file file2.hevc
>
> file file3.hevc
>
> ...
>
> file file48.hevc

then run,

> ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -vf tile=8x6 -vframes 1 -q:v 1 grid.jpg